# NeRF to Pointcloud

Tags: computer-vision, rendering, photogrammetry, structure-from-motion, colmap

I am currently trying to study **Neural radiance fields** and i was looking for a way to extract a **pointcloud** from it.

In particular i am trying to use the **COLMAP** pointcloud and compare the real color with the one predicted by NeRF. Unfortunately i am not getting good results as the colors predicted are different from the real ones. I think it is for a  different scaling of the representation of COLMAP and NeRF.

Do anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Comment: What are you attempting to learn from comparing COLMAP point-cloud to sampled point cloud from NeRF?

Are you saying that your current comparison between NeRF and COLMAP is that their different?

Given NeRF is ML, and COLMAP pointclouds have to average the feature color between different images the feature was found in, I'd expect them to be different

Sidenote: Have you taken a look at guassian splatting?